# Différence entre isolement et isolation

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je voudrais savoir la différence entre “isolement” et “isolation”.

Dans quels contextes utilise-t-on chacun de ces deux mots ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isolement est utilisé pour parler d'une personne, par exemple "il a un sentiment d'isolement".Tu peux le remplacer par "mis(e) à l'écart" dans ta phrase.

Isolation est utilisé pour parler d'une maison, ou plus généralement d'un objet, dans le sens où elle isole la chaleur/fraicheur ou le son : "L'isolation de cette maison est super!"

Comment: On emploie isolation aussi pour parler des personnes. Dans le cas d'une incarcération on parle plutôt de cellule d'isolement mais dans le milieu hospitalier on dit aussi bien, isolation qu'isolement. Voir aussi le sens B du mot dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/isolation)  Et on emploie aussi isolement pour des choses, voir des exemples dans le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/isolement).